# Prove that if $C$ is a connected subset of $(X,\tau)$ and $B\subseteq X$ such that $C\subseteq B\subseteq \overline{C}$ then $B$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $C$ be a connected subset of a topological space $(X,\tau)$ and $B\subseteq X$ such that $C\subseteq B\subseteq \overline{C}$. Now it is required to prove that $B$ is connected. The following is my attempt.

Suppose $f:B\to \{0,1\}$ is continuous where $\{0,1\}$ is endowed with its discrete topology. Now since $C\subseteq B$ and $f$ is continuous we have $f(\overline{C})\subseteq\overline{f(C)}$, whence $f(C)\subseteq f(B)\subseteq f(\overline{C})\subseteq \overline{f(C)}$. But $f(C)$ is either $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$ as $C$ is connected, and $f(C)$ is closed. Thus $f(C)=\overline{f(C)}$. Therefore $f(B)=f(C)$. Thus $f$ is constant. Hence $B$ is connected.

Is the above argument alright? Thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me. Although you will always have $f(C) = \overline{f(C)}$, since you're in the discrete topology.

Comment: There is a slight problem with how you put it though : you talk about $f(\overline{C})$ without having defined it ($f$ is only defined on $B$)

Comment: @Max How would you remedy it?

Comment: I would show that you can extend $f$ to $\overline{C}$ so that it'd still be continuous

Comment: No, the domain of f needs to be the closure of C.

Comment: How about this? $B=\overline{C}\cap B$; so $f(B)=f(\overline{C}\cap B)\subseteq \overline{f(C \cap B)}=\overline{f(C)}$ by continuity of $f$. Now since $f \restriction_C$ is constant $f$ is constant.

Comment: @Janitha357@Max. Basically that's what I was going to say: Consider $C$ as a dense subspace of the space $B$, and replace $\overline C$ in the proof with $Cl_B(C).$ The result can also be re-stated as follows: If $C$ is a dense connected subset of a space $B,$  then $ B$ is connected.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Got it. The problem makes perfect sense when it is restated as you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With functions another way: by definition $C$ is dense in $\overline{C}$, so $C$ is dense in $B$ as well and $\{0,1\}$ is Hausdorff, and if $f: B \to \{0,1\}$ is continuous, $f|C$ is constant with value $c \in \{0,1\}$. But then $1_c$ and $f$ coincide on the dense set $C$ of $B$, so also on $B$ and $f$ is constant with the same value. Done: $B$ is connected.

Comment: Why the stipulation $\{0,1\}$ is Hausdorff? Is it because you want " $1_c$ and $f$ coincide on the dense set $C$ of $B$, so also on $B$"?

Comment: @Janitha357 I'm using the theorem: Let $X$ be a space with a dense subset $D$, and $Y$ be Hausdorff. If $f,g: X \to Y$ are continuous and $f|D  =g|D$ (so $f$ and $g$ coincide on $D$), then $f = g$ on $X$.

Comment: I thought so! You always have different proofs and it is great.